# How to configure tsconfig.json to use global @types/node

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I can't use global @types/node because it throws an error when compiling. I have to install @types/node locally for this to work.

Comment: Yes that's how you're supposed to do it usually. Why would you want it to use a globally installed version? That just gets messy when you have other people working on the project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.